# Acessar variável de dentro do escopo da promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promises

Tenho um factory que deve acessar outros dois services. Sendo a seguinte estrutura:

```
angular.module('my.module')
.factory('ServiceMain', ServiceMain);

ServiceMain.$inject = ['ServicePrimary', 'ServiceSecondary'];

function ServiceMain(ServicePrimary, ServiceSecondary){

  var service = {
       execute: execute
  }

  return service;

  function execute(){

    ServicePrimary.getData().then(function(result){

      var arrayData = [];

      var indiceForSync = 0;
      for(var indice = 0; indice < result.length; indice++ ){

        if(result[indice].valor <= 0){
            continue;
        }

        arrayData[indiceForSync] = {
            clientes: result[indice],
          pacotes: []
        }

        indiceForSync++;
      }

      if(arrayData.length) {

            for (var indiceData = 0; indiceData < arrayData.length; indiceData++) {

              ServiceSecondary.getPackages(arrayData[indiceData].valor).then(function(packs){
                //Aqui nao eh possivel enxergar o arrayData...
                for(var indicePacks = 0; indicePacks < packs.length; indicePacks++ ){
                  //a ideia era chamar o array data para preencher o array pacotes
                  arrayData[indiceData].pacotes[indicePacks] = packs[indicePacks];
                }
              });

          }//end for

      }
    });
  }
}
```

Dentro da chamada do segundo service (ServiceSecondary), dentro da promise eu não possuo acesso à variável arrayData. Já tentei invocando o this (algo como: `var vm = this;` ) e em seguida declarando-a com `vm.arrayData`, e em último ato, tentei utilizar o $rootScope, porém nada funciona.

Existe uma maneira de acessar essa variável dentro do escopo da promise? ou será a implementação que está com problemas?

Answer (score 1):

Uma variável referindo o `this` (como `var vm = this`) deve funcionar sim, mas lembre-se de inicializá-la no escopo do `ServiceMain`, não na função `execute`.
Aconselho também usar o *loop* do **Angular** (`angular.forEach`) para fazer as interações com os objetos.